# Serverless Error, CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework, serverless

I have the following error.

Serverless: Operation failed!

```
Serverless Error ---------------------------------------
An error occurred: phoneNumberTable - CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename mysite-api-phonenumber-dev and update the stack again…
```

I tried deleting the database to see if it could re-create it then but it still gives the same error and doesn’t remake the database? **What do I do here?**

What I did was recently change in my serverless.yml file the following for the resource.

```
phoneNumberTable: #This table is used to track phone numbers used in the system
      Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
      Properties:
        TableName: ${self:custom.phoneNumberTable}
        AttributeDefinitions: #UserID in this case will be created once and constantly updated as it changes with status regarding the user.
          - AttributeName: phoneNumber
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: phoneNumber
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
            ReadCapacityUnits: ${self:custom.dynamoDbCapacityUnits.${self:custom.pstage}}
            WriteCapacityUnits: ${self:custom.dynamoDbCapacityUnits.${self:custom.pstage}}
```

I accidentally created it with userId when I was copying and pasting so I changed it to phoneNumber for the hash key but the change won't reflect now!

Edit::

**I found a solution but it's terrible**.  If I do sls remove --stage dev it will remove everything for my stage, but literally everything... then I have to do sls deploy --stage dev to start the deploy over again, in the meantime my database is cleared of all data... there has to be a better way somehow.

Comment: your solution was good for me... the stage was "dev" and the lost data was not a problem in my case. thanks!

Answer (score 15):

The AWS recommended solution is to rename:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/

Comment: Could you explain the cause of the problem? I could not understand the explanation mentioned in AWS page you provided.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin I think the issue here is that when a resource needs replacing during an update, CloudFormation creates the new resource before it deletes the old resource, so that if something bad happens and CF has to rollback the stack update, your original resources (with their original names) still exist. It can't do that if it cannot autogenerate names for the resources because the user has dictated custom names.

Answer (score 3):

I found I needed to insert some variables to make it work.

Environment variable:
`USERS_TABLE: "users-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}-${self:provider.environment.BUILD_NUMBER}"`

Table name:
`TableName: ${self:provider.environment.USERS_TABLE}`

In my code:

`const existingUser = await dynamoDb.get({
    TableName: process.env.USERS_TABLE,
    Key: {
      email,
    },
  }).promise();`

Comment: Are the variables always the same in your case? What happens if you change the variables?

Comment: I ended up having to add a variable that changes every time `BUILD_NUMBER`. Updated my answer. However, I actually decided to switch to MySQL instead of Dynamo for what I'm working on.

Comment: Funny you mention that I did also switch to MySQL I have some other posts on how I automated that with serverless

Comment: Nice. Yeah, I found Dynamo to be too limited. I'm building a SaaS and I'm used to being able to easily query on different fields and create indexes and stuff like that.

Comment: This is not a solution, I mean it is but not really, this basically deletes your existing table and you lose your data, if I understand it correcty

Answer (score 3):

Rename your resource to something else, deploy it, rename it back (if you need) and deploy again.

Answer (score 2):

This problem usually occurs when you modify the partition keys of your DynamoDB table. DynamoDB cannot make the change for you. You must delete the database, making sure to back it up and recreate it. Once the new DB has been created, you can perform your migration.

Comment: Yes!  This is exactly what happened to me.   Along with deleting the table, I had to delete the CloudFormation stack--and all stacks that relied on it.  So, nearly the entire deployment.  Once that was done, re-running the table stack succeeded.

Comment: @Richard I also thought I had to delete the whole stack. I didn't realize I had a parameter_overrides = "...TableName=\"..._events\"" so renaming in my templates was causing the same error to repeat and I thought something was cached at AWS.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/

This error typically occurs when a stack update tries to replace resources that have properties with custom names. AWS CloudFormation doesn't replace a resource that has a custom name unless that custom name is changed to a different name. To prevent a stack failure and avoid the error message, change any resources with custom names to use different names before you update a stack.

To resolve this you need change `TableName` to some other string. What that will do: Serverless will delete your table (because that's no longer a part of a stack) and will create a new table with a new name and a keys.